# How to check a check box if it's value is in database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am newbie from asp.net

i wanted to asked how the data grid view that i have already insert in database?

the view like this
Before

[image]

After

[image]

Thank for help.

Comment: Uh? That didnt even make 1% sense to me. Please rephrase it

Comment: The same image is linked twice, can't tell the difference.

Comment: The difference between the images are the checkboxes on the left.

Comment: I didn't get you. If you wish to have an answer ask things clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the question is certainly not clear but i  guess u want to write values to your checkbox which are coming from database add following to your checkbox. It should help

```
checked='<%#Eval("YourCheckboxValueColumnName")%>'
```